# Delete repeated Ids from Table - Performance Improvement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, query-performance

I have a table with repeated codes, I need to clean the table removing the repeated, but having at least one left of then in the table.

My table is this:

```
FriendlyFunctionCode      MemberFirmId     FunctionLevel3Desc
1                         Value1           Value2
1                         Value2           Value3
2                         Value4           Value5
```

I need something like this: (It doesn't matter which row is left, just to have at least one)

```
FriendlyFunctionCode      MemberFirmId     FunctionLevel3Desc
1                         Value1           Value2
2                         Value4           Value5
```

I have this query, but the performance is awful

```
SELECT MemberFirmId, FriendlyFunctionCode
INTO #ToDeleteRepeated
FROM [dbo].[FirmFunction]
GROUP BY MemberFirmId, FriendlyFunctionCode
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1

DECLARE @Code VARCHAR(100), @Desc VARCHAR(250)

WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #ToDeleteRepeated) > 0) 
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Code = FriendlyFunctionCode FROM #ToDeleteRepeated
    WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [FirmFunction] WHERE FriendlyFunctionCode = @Code) > 0) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Desc = FunctionLevel3Desc FROM [FirmFunction] WHERE FriendlyFunctionCode = @Code
        DELETE FROM [FirmFunction] WHERE FriendlyFunctionCode = @Code AND FunctionLevel3Desc = @Desc
    END
END
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: first do you care which record you keep or delete when they have different values related to the FriendlyFunctionCode?  Your query suggests you don't.  Actually just to note your query would delete multiple records if the FunctionLevel3Desc is repeated too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT MemberFirmId, FriendlyFunctionCode, 
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by FriendlyFunctionCode      ORDER BY FriendlyFunctionCode      ) AS RN
                FROM [dbo].[FirmFunction]
        )
        DELETE CTE WHERE CTE.RN >1
```

Comment: I think you need partition just by `FriendlyFunctionCode`

Comment: Awesome answer, tried it too and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Delete using CTE with row_number()

```
;with cte as (
select *, row_number() over(partition by friendlyfunctioncode order by memberfirmid) rn
 from deletingtable)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

This executes with below execution plan:

Table/Clustered index scan --> sort(if no index) --> segment --> Sequence Project --> Filter and then delete,

If it has proper index on FriendlyFunctionCode it executes faster in single scan

Comment: What about possible additional indexes on the table?

Comment: Did not delete repeated.

Comment: Means, if there are more indexes, then those indexes will have overhead due to delete

Answer (score 1):

You could use a windowing function like this. Saves having to use a cursor (which don't perform well in SQL Server). You can run the inner select on it's own to see what it's doing with the row number.

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (FriendlyFunctionCode int, MemberFirmId nvarchar(10), FunctionLevel3Desc nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES
(1,'Value1','Value2')
,(1,'Value2','Value3')
,(2,'Value4','Value5')
```

Query

```
SELECT
a.FriendlyFunctionCode
,a.MemberFirmId
,a.FunctionLevel3Desc
INTO #SavedData
FROM
(
    SELECT
    FriendlyFunctionCode
    ,MemberFirmId
    ,FunctionLevel3Desc
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FriendlyFunctionCode ORDER BY FriendlyFunctionCode) RowNum
    FROM #TestData
) a
WHERE a.RowNum = 1

TRUNCATE TABLE #TestData

INSERT INTO #TestData (FriendlyFunctionCode, MemberFirmId, FunctionLevel3Desc)
SELECT
FriendlyFunctionCode
,MemberFirmId
,FunctionLevel3Desc
FROM #SavedData

DROP TABLE #SavedData
```

Result

```
FriendlyFunctionCode    MemberFirmId    FunctionLevel3Desc  
1                       Value1          Value2              
2                       Value4          Value5
```

Comment: right concept but doesn't actually delete the record

Comment: That's fair. I've updated my answer to truncate the original table and insert the saved records. Should perform better than a delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use MAX and group on the FunctionCode.

```
SELECT 
   FriendlyFunctionCode, 
   MAX(MemberFirmId) as MemberFirmId, 
   MAX(FunctionLevel3Desc) as FuncationLevel3Desc
INTO #StagingTable
FROM
   FirmFunction
GROUP BY
   FriendlyFunctionCode
```

Then Truncate Your Table, and select back into it... or just create a table all together and insert the distinct (max) records into it.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE FirmFunction

INSERT INTO FirmFunction (FriendlyFunctionCode,MemberFirmId,FunctionLevel3Desc)
SELECT * FROM #StagingTable
```

This is less safe than creating a table FirmFunction2 for example with the same schema as your original and then just inserting into it, then renaming it....

```
SELECT TOP 1 INTO FirmFunction2 FROM FirmFunction WHERE 1=0

INSERT INTO FirmFunction2 (FriendlyFunctionCode, MemberFirmId, FunctionLevel3Desc)
SELECT 
       FriendlyFunctionCode, 
       MAX(MemberFirmId) as MemberFirmId, 
       MAX(FunctionLevel3Desc) as FuncationLevel3Desc
    INTO #StagingTable
    FROM
       FirmFunction
    GROUP BY
       FriendlyFunctionCode
```

Then you can check the date in FirmFunction2 and if you are satisfied... rename it after dropping the other table.

Comment: Good approach, dit it and work like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @Rednaxel I just want to highlight that CTE's are great, but use with extreme caution. Often beginners (not saying you are a beginner) use them like temp tables where temp tables can't be used. There isn't anything wrong with this, usually, except that CTE's can affect the original data source as you are intentionally doing in your situation. Thus, if you execute and insert, delete, etc using the CTE there is no going back. Be sure the syntax is correct... you partition by and order by correctly, etc. The method i provided isn't as streamlined, but is less prone to mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll be careful with CTE.